# Constant viewport size across all devices with PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, viewport

I've got PhoneGap Android app that is exactly 480 pixel width and I want to set viewport size to this size on every possible Android's device

I've tried this tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480, user-scalable=no" />
```

But it was ignored by all devices and emulators I tested with. Then I tried:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.67, minimum-scale=0.67, maximum-scale=0.67, user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

And this worked, but only on some (smaller) devices. On mu Samsung GT it gives correct 480 pixel width viewport, but when launched on tablet it gives 800 pixel width viewport.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several hours of debugging I finally found a solution:

WebView *will* ignore width of the viewport unless it is explicty told to be loaded in OverviewMode. So if anyone come here from Google, here's the solution:

Add to your Java source:

```
public class YourGame extends DroidGap
{       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init(); // Don't forget this, you'll get runtime error otherwise!

    // The following does the trick:
    super.appView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    super.appView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.htm");
}
```

Comment: what exactly does that do? I tried putting that in my code and everything is now huge / zoomed in and there's a ton of blank space I can scroll around in

Comment: Where would I put this? Is there a solution for iphones as well?

Comment: @JonasÄppelgran In your Java code at `project/src/com/your/namespace/Project.java` - Keep it mind that this is the solution for older version of PhoneGap - I've used it in 2.2, don't know if it actually works in newer releases

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why, but I had to remove `, target-densityDpi=device-dpi` from the viewport tag to get this to work - the accepted answer didn't help me.

*using a Samsung Galaxy Nexus*